# List the department name with the least number of employees

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

There are two tables, employee and dept:

[image: See this screenshot for column names]

How can I join the two tables and select the department with the least number of employees?

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better to answer if you provided the table structure.

But give this a try:

```
SELECT deptname 
FROM dept 
WHERE deptid = (SELECT distinct deptid 
                FROM employee
                ORDER BY COUNT(dept) limit 1);
```

Comment: Error at Command Line:5 Column:24
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Parenthesis look okay too me :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm only answering because `MIN` isn't needed and `LIMIT` isn't Oracle:

```
select d.*
from (select deptid, count(*) as cnt
      from employees e
      group by deptid
      order by count(*) asc
     ) d
where rownum = 1;
```

In Oracle 12C+, you don't need the subquery:

```
      select deptid, count(*) as cnt
      from employees e
      group by deptid
      order by count(*) asc
      fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: ^this query is showing all the departments with number of employees in them. i want to list the one with least employees

Comment: @AhsonJunani . . . The queries did not show all departments.  They showed one department, but it happened to be the one with the most employees.  Using `asc` instead of `desc` gets the fewest employees.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT deptid,
       deptname,
       employeeCount
FROM
(
    SELECT dept.deptid AS deptid,
           dept.deptname,
           COUNT( dept.deptid ) AS employeeCount
    FROM dept
    JOIN employee ON dept.deptid = employee.deptid
    GROUP BY dept.deptid,
             dept.deptname
)
GROUP BY deptid
HAVING employeeCount = MIN( employeeCount );
```

This statement starts with the inner query joining `dept` to `employee` on the shared field `deptid`.  It then groups the resulting rows by department and returns to the outer query the department's `id` and `name` along with a count of employees for that department.

The outer query groups the data by department again, then selects the details of the department(s) having a count of employees equal to the minimum count of employees.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Error at Command Line:12 Column:3
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Get rid of the `AS employeeCounter`.

Comment: Error at Command Line:8 Column:19
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Correction (attempt) posted.  Please try again.

Comment: Error at Command Line:7 Column:12
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Correction (attempt) posted.  Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Hi :) so my answer is a bit ugly, and full of nested queries. but I tested it and it worked for me...

```
-- First I created a couple of test tables and added a few records 
drop table dept;
drop table employee;
create table dept (deptid number primary key, deptname varchar(20));
create table employee(employee_id number primary key, names varchar(20),
deptid number,foreign key (deptid) references dept(deptid));
insert into dept values(1,'HR');
insert into dept values(2,'Finance');
insert into dept values(3,'IT');
insert into employee values(1,'Tina',1);
insert into employee values(2,'Rob',1);
insert into employee values(3,'Lisa',1);
insert into employee values(4,'Will',2);
insert into employee values(5,'Lina',2);
insert into employee values(6,'Ethel',2);
insert into employee values(7,'Trevor',1);
insert into employee values(8,'Alanea',1);
insert into employee values(9,'Matthew',1);
insert into employee values(10,'Maddie',3);
insert into employee values(11,'Anna',1);
-- According to the added records, the answer we are looking for should be
the department name IT

-- select the department name from department table
select d.deptname from dept d, 
/* This is where it gets ugly - basically, it counts the number of
employees in each department, then finds the id of the department that had
the smallest count */
(select deptid from 
(select count(deptid) as counter, deptid from employee group by deptid) 
where counter =( select min(counter)from 
(select count(deptid) as counter, deptid from employee group by deptid))) minid
-- join the tables using deptid
where d.deptid = minid.deptid;
```

This query gave the correct answer for me even when I changed the records to make finance the correct answer.
If you have any questions give me a yell through the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select department_name, count(employee_id)
from department d
inner join employee e
on d.employee_id = e.employee_id
having count(employee_id) = 
(
select min(count(employee_id)) /*This query returns minimum count*/
from department d
inner join employee e
on d.employee_id = e.employee_id
group by department_name
)
group by department_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

`WITH temp
  AS 
  (SELECT e1.department_id, count(e1.employee_id) emp_count
  FROM hr.employees e1
 GROUP BY e1.department_id)
  SELECT  d1.department_name, t1.emp_count  employee_count
    FROM temp t1
        ,hr.departments d1
    WHERE t1.department_id = d1.department_id(+)
      AND NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT 1
         FROM temp t2
         WHERE t2.emp_count < t1.emp_count)
 ORDER BY 2,1         ;`